# how to stop menu when you stop scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can't figure out how to stop menu when you stop scrolling. When you scroll down menu has to hide and show only when stop scrolling or scrolling up. My code work only when you scroll up, I would appreciate if you help me.

js:

```
$(window).scroll({
    previousTop: 0
    }, 
    function () {
        var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentTop < this.previousTop) {
            $("header").css("display", "none");
        } else {
        $("header").css("display", "block");
    }
    this.previousTop = currentTop;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're only checking for when the `currentTop` is less than the `previousTop`. That would be only when going up.

Really, if you want to trigger it any time you're scrolling, you need to just do `currentTop != previousTop`, which will work in both directions.